# Using multiple mirrors in Michelson Interferometer

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, reflection, interference, interferometry

The number of mirrors typically used in Michelson Interferometer is 2. I am looking up the respective [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_interferometer) and [MIT's youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-u3IEgcTiQ).

I am wondering, for the sake of one of my experiment, whether more than 2 mirrors can be used in the interferometer? I require the traversing mirror to be in a remote location and moving is a non-orthogonal line. I intend to use more mirrors to get the interference pattern. I wish to know if this is feasible.

A pictorial representation is as this:
[image]

Comment: you may want to search for corner cube Interferometer

Comment: @f5r5e5d Thanks. The search took me to places where the measuring mirror was way further than the reference mirror! Gotcha